# Deploy react aplication

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I tried to deploy my website on github I used followid commands:

1. "homepage": "https://neqts.github.io/PortfolioTopor",
2. npm install gh-pages --save-dev
3. "predeploy": "npm run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
4. git remote add origin https://github.com/neqts/PortfolioTopor.git
5. npm run deploy
6. And after clicking enviroment gh-pages i get only navbar uploaded on site https://neqts.github.io/PortfolioTopor/

Help...

Comment: It's hard to show, but the local host page is working fine, and there are some subpages on it, I wonder if it could be due to AOS animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peeking at the minified code for your site, I can see

```
Object(r.jsx)(r.Fragment, {
  children: Object(r.jsxs)(a.a, {
    children: [
      Object(r.jsx)(x, {}),
      Object(r.jsx)(j.c, {
        children: Object(r.jsx)(j.a, {
          path: "/",
          exact: !0,
          component: L,
        }),
      }),
    ],
  }),
});
```

which smells a lot like a `react-router` route.

Your router expects exactly a `/` path, but your path is, when deployed, `/PortfolioTopor/`.

New versions of `react-router` apparently support [a `basename` prop on the router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) – you should probably set that to `/PortfolioTopor/` too.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm just learning React how to change this ?

Comment: Do you have a `<BrowserRouter>` in your code? Try making it `<BrowserRouter basename="/PortfolioTopor/">`.

Comment: Oh, also, it shouldn't apparently have a trailing slash.

Comment: I added the whole website and branch master with all the code, if you could have a look, I would be very grateful, here I added browser route https://github.com/neqts/PortfolioTomaszTopor/blob/master/portfolio/src/components/pages/Home.js

Comment: You added it in the wrong place, it doesn't do anything there. You're not using react-router in any sensible way at all, so you can just replace https://github.com/neqts/PortfolioTomaszTopor/blob/fb3e3504de25aea2f9a8ec55e088a811459c7a6e/portfolio/src/App.js#L10-L21 with `return <Home />` for now.

Comment: You mean somethink like this ? https://github.com/neqts/TToporr/blob/master/portfolio/src/App.js

Comment: Bay the way there is a option to talk with you on discord or somethink?

Comment: I'm open to paid private consulting/mentoring sessions on Codementor. The link is in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to your react-application.
Github pages display only what you build.

Try to run `npm run build` and `serve -s build` on your locale project to see your project in "production". If it's display only the navbar, you need to fix your react-project.

PS: I've looking your repository `PortfolioTopor` and I saw that you only have one branch "gh-pages". You haven't pushed your master branch on github, but that's the purpose of github-pages to have master and gh-pages branch.

Comment: Can u take a look I added master branch with source code https://github.com/neqts/PortfolioTomaszTopor I will be really gratefull